Appium inspector - Cannot connect to the Dart Observatory URL - Flutter
I'm trying to create a session in appium inspector for android app which developed in Flutter.  this is the capabilities set:
{   "appium:automationName": "Flutter", 
  "appium:platformName": "Android",
  "appium:deviceName": "emulator-5554",
  "appium:app": "app-base-debug.apk",
"appium:appPackage": "com.app.example",
"appium:appActivity": "com.app.example.MainActivity" 
}
I'm getting error:
Failed to create session. An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot connect to the Dart Observatory URL ws://127.0.0.1:39199/r5EjPR0pGpc=/ws. Check the server log for more details
Any ideas how to fix this issue ?
this are the list of drivers that was installed:
✔ Listing available drivers

uiautomator2@3.9.3 [installed (npm)]
flutter@2.11.0 [installed (npm)]
xcuitest@7.34.1 [installed (npm)]`

When I check:
wscat -c ws://127.0.0.1:39199
error: socket hang up
The same issue occuresd on ios platform.
appium inspector create session when capability is UiAutomator2"
